# Display of checkbox in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've got the following html that I display with cefsharp in a wpf app:

```
<label><input type="checkbox" class="form-control"/> Steaksandwich</label>
```

I would like to ask if it is by design that the blue border that appears if the checkbox is active does not stretch around the label as well? This is how the effect looks in my chrome:

[image: effect does not stretch around label]

If it is by design, can I somehow change it or remove the effect? If it's not by design, then what am I doing wrong??

Comment: Not able to view that effect in Chrome browser

Comment: I'm using cefsharp in wpf, will add that to my question, thought it was chrome specific

Comment: Of course it doesn’t “stretch around the label”, because it is applied to the input field. And only that makes sense, since the label doesn’t have to be _around_ the input, it could as well be before/after it, or in a completely different place altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually we don't use the class "form-control" in check box. Just remove it and you'll be OK.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `for=` to create a link between the label and the input:

```html
<input id="mybox" type="checkbox" class="form-control"/>
<label for="mybox"> Steaksandwich</label>
```

Comment: That did not change the effect, unfortunatly.

Answer (score 0):

That line is added by browser, you can remove it by adding this on your css
* - means all elements on the page. I hope it will work

```
*{
outline:none;
}
```

Comment: As stated by in [this MDN document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Writing_efficient_CSS), you should "avoid universal rules". While it may make things simpler, it adds a hefty load to the rendering engine. You should list the specific, relevant, tags instead.